# Change interfaces of beans through maven

Tags: java, maven

I want to have two versions of the same interfaces (by same I mean it has the same name, and it does have the same methods) that are implemented by beans. One interface has specific annotations, and the other one doesn't. How can I manage to choose which of the two types of interfaces I want in maven? Is there a way that I can use an argument in `mvn` to get to my goal?

For example:

BeanA implements InterfaceA.

InterfaceA exists one time with specific annotations, and one time without.

EDIT: Optional solution: The interfaces are allowed to have different name, but they must be interchangable in the beans.

Comment: 'BeanA implements some.package.name.InterfaceA ?

Comment: @vikingsteve But how can I accomplish making InterfaceA interchangable with another interface without manually removing InterfaceA from the list of implemented interfaces of BeanA.

Comment: Can both the interfaces extend a "parent interface" ?

Comment: @vikingsteve yes